# Parsing and reformatting date string using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parsing

Given a CSV-file containing the following line:

> HEAD;1;49999;8-10-2017;;;

.. I need to reformat the date given as d-m-yyyy into fixed length dd.mm.yyyy and/or yyyy-mm-dd (fixed, naturally implying double digit day and month)

While I see much of the cleverness behind PowerShell, I find it rather unwieldy. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you already know how to import the csv-file in powershell this should point you into the right direction: `Get-Date 8-10-2017 -Format "MM.dd.yyyy"`

Comment: That works like a charm, except it misinterprets the positioning of original day and month. 8-10 means Oct 8, not Aug 10 which is what the cmdlet spits out..

Comment: In that case you will have to tell powershell which culturesetting to use: `$Culture = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo 'en-us';
Get-Date ([datetime]::parse("8-10-2017",$Culture)) -Format dd.MM.yyyy`

Comment: I want to like PowerShell so very bad.. Thank you for a complete and excellent solution, whatever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was essentially the problem addressed by the [**Idera PowerTip of the Day** for October 12, 2017](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/converting-weird-data-formats). The solution presented was to use the [`ParseExact` method of the `DateTime` .NET class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx). Assuming that you've extracted the date from the CSV and stored it in the variable `$ActionDateString`, you would then convert it to a `DateTime` object:

```
$DT = [DateTime]::ParseExact($ActionDateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", $null)
```

and then you can use the `DateTime` object `$DT` as you please.